# What is the Main Job of Logical Link Layer in Layer 2

Tags: networking, osi, data-link-layer

I am curious to know what Logical Link Layer does.  What is its main significance?  Is it part of Software?

I am looking for some details of LLC.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_Model

Answer (score 1):

The LLC sublayer is primarily concerned with:

```
* Multiplexing protocols transmitted over the MAC layer (when transmitting) and demultiplexing them (when receiving).
* Providing flow and error control
```

The protocol used for LLC in IEEE 802 networks and in some non-IEEE 802 networks such as FDDI is specified by the [IEEE 802.2 standard](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee802/download/802.2-1998.pdf).

Some non-IEEE 802 protocols can be thought of as being split into MAC and LLC layers. For example, while HDLC specifies both MAC functions (framing of packets) and LLC functions (protocol multiplexing, flow control, detection, and error control through a retransmission of dropped packets when indicated), some protocols such as Cisco HDLC can use HDLC-like packet framing and their own LLC protocol.

An LLC header tells the Data Link layer what to do with a packet once a frame is received. It works like this: A host will receive a frame and look in the LLC header to find out where the packet is destined for - for example, the IP protocol at the Network layer or IPX.

LLC also does ciphering and deciphering of SN-PDU (SNDCP)packets.

The above details are found on Wikipedia.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Link_Control

Comment: oops sory derobert. i didn't knew that he copied from wiki. i ask sorry for giving vote to viky.

Comment: @mahesh: No need to apologize, you can't be expected to find all plagiarism.

Comment: Hi Guys. Good feedback.
@derobert - you say its plagiarism, can you please let me know where i have mentioned that this is what i wrote. 
The question was lame and @mahesh didnt even try to look for the answer.
The answer was to the question.
Anyway thanks.

Comment: @Viky: Your answer is a copy & paste of that Wikipedia article, w/o giving credit to Wikipedia. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plagiarism. It also violates the license (GFDL) that Wikipedia is distributed under. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Copyrights

Comment: Thanks for adding the citation. Unfortunately Stackoverflow considers the vote too old to change now :-(